# ¿ Correr un CSS en local / Linux?

Tags: html, css

Descargue un repo de git, en el cual hay unicamente archivos css sin ningun HTML asociado (el css tiene muchas clases), hay alguna forma de correr esos archivos sin un HTML asociado? Necesito hacer unos cambios (de color y estilo a unos objetos puntuales), pero sin el HTML no se como hacerlo ya que no los puedo identificar puntualmente, al no poder probar no puedo saber si lo que estoy cambiando está bien.

Comment: Para mi la respuesta, al menos para tí es NO, es lógico que lo utilizarás con html, entonces que sentido tendría usar el css si no es así? y menos si no logras identificar lo que quieres cambiar, eso solo indica que no tienes conocimientos de css. Sisabes usar css, puedes cambiar propiedades sin necesidar de ver el html.

Comment: Como hago para cambiar el color de un botón especifico, si no tengo el HTML para saber el identificador del botón que quiero cambiar?

Comment: Si no sabes el identificador del elemento, será muy difícil hacerlo. Es como adivinar qué llave abre una puerta específica en un centenar de llaves, pero sin tener la puerta para probar la llave. o_O

Comment: Si necesitas ver los resultados necesariamente necesitas el html, un csss sin html no sirve de nada

Comment: y que tal si corres esos script y lo navegas en la pagina web, boton derecho inspeccionar y mira alli esta el nombre prueba a ver si te funciona; si no re funciona seguramente tu script se ejecuta antes que se genere el HTML

Answer (score -1):

Podrías crear etiquetas de HTML, para que veas que cambios se van realizando y de esa manera identificas cada uno, ya que es complicado ejecutar un CSS sin HTML.

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow, mientras aplaudo la intención de responder, te recomiendo leer [answer] pues, en mi opinión, tu respuesta carece del detalle suficiente, de acuerdo a los estándares del sitio.

Answer (score -1):

Dado a que tienes solo una hoja de estilo requieres de tu HTML para poderlos aplicar en si e identificar cada uno de ellos por sus etiquetas, id, clases, etc. Relaciona tus estilos con etiquetas las cuales puedes disponer de:
body para el contenido
head para información sobre el documento
div división dentro del contenido
a para enlaces
strong para poner el texto en negrita
br para saltos de línea
H1…H6 para títulos dentro del contenido
img para añadir imágenes al documento
ol, ul para listas desordenadas,

para elementos dentro de la lista
p para parágrafos
span para estilos de una parte del texto